# Should tag "Linux" be renamed to "GNU/Linux" otherwise created or added to synonym?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, tag-disambiguation

Questions using Linux tag may deal with the operating system and not only the Linux kernel.

> The Free Software Foundation uses the name GNU/Linux to refer to the
>   operating system family, as well as specific distributions, to
>   emphasize that most Linux distributions are not just the Linux kernel,
>   and that they have in common not only the kernel, but also numerous
>   utilities and libraries, a large proportion of which are from the GNU
>   project. ([Extract from Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux))

So, to avoid confusion, I suggest to rename tag "Linux" to "GNU/Linux" or create a new one and edit all questions (ouch!) or at least create a synonym.

*We have to give to Caesar what is Caesar's (Richard Stallman ;-).*

Comment: My personal opinion is that everybody knows what's meant when a question is tagged [linux] (which is quite a broad tag anyway).

Comment: Plus the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/linux/info) mentions the debate about the name already.

Comment: And what about create a synonym? Lot of people vote down but without reason...

Comment: Is there any confusion in the first place? Could you provide some example questions/comments/discussion? The tag excerpt already stated that it's about "*programming using Linux APIs or Linux-specific behavior, not just because you happen to run your code on Linux.*"

Comment: @Genjo, voting in meta is different. Since you posted a "feature-request", people may be down-voting to express disagreement with your proposal. Also, votes do not need to be justified; neither here nor in the main site. Do not complain about down-votes, it's just noise.

Comment: This Wikipedia article you cite, what is its title? :)

Comment: @Genjo don't worry about the downvotes. It merely means we're almost unequivocally agreeing that we do **not** want to rename the tag. People have no obligation to justify their opinion.

Comment: @DanBron the fact that Wikipedia is generally biased against software freedom is nothing new. Same for DRM: the correct term is Digital Restrictions Management, not Digital Rights Management, because it's all about restricting what a user can do, but the people who invest into Wikipedia hosting want to push their agenda and so here we are. https://www.defectivebydesign.org/what_is_drm_digital_restrictions_management

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the tag "Linux" should not be renamed to "GNU/Linux". The GNU version of Linux is a subset of all Linux versions, and Linux is a subset of the Unix-like operating systems. The GNU/Linux systems are OS built around the Linux kernel with a general set of libraries and utilities in common, however if someone builds a Linux OS that strays far enough from the common libraries and utilities yet uses the Linux kernel, then it is Linux but not GNU/Linux.

It's sort of like saying a square is a rectangle, and a rectangle is a polygon. You can go one way (Square is all three things), however not every polygon is a rectangle or a square.

If we were to make this change, it would be placing the "GNU" (square) limitation on the whole set of Linux (rectangle) objects, which is simply not true for every OS in the set of all Linux systems.

---

Disclaimer: There is some degree of opinion based in this answer, as the exact definition of GNU/Linux is still up for debate. People have made arguments to say that making an OS based off the Linux kernel is enough to call it GNU/Linux, among other things that make this nomenclature not completely exact. The [tag wiki for linux](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/linux/info) goes into more detail about this, and you can find articles online about people arguing how the name should be used.

Comment: And what about creating a synonym which suggest using "Linux" when typing GNU/Linux? Should I ask this in a new question?

Comment: The meta question tells it's about the questions which are relevant only to GNU/Linux, and it's not suggesting to change tag name for questions which are actually about the Linux (kernel).

Comment: It is entirely false. There is no official "gnu linux distribution". There is "gnu hurd", which is based on another kernel, and wasn't ever enough popular to be even well-known. The intended role of the "gnu linux" is filled by the Debian in practice, although the Debian is organizationally independent from the FSF. From the sentence *"The GNU version of Linux..."* is your post false, it doesn't exist. Stallman himself is using, as far I know, Debian.

Comment: However, the overwhelming majority of the most essential Linux tools were part of the Gnu's Hurd project originally. Without the GNU project, Linux wouldn't exist, or it would be essentially different and much lesser developed. Using only GNU software, a Linux system (except the kernel) is practically self-compilable. On this reason, the GNU/Linux terminology is the correct one. If it is practical, is another question. But saying that it would be incorrect on a false reasoning...

Comment: @Peterh Just read up on the stuff you've brought up, and you're absolutely right, I was under a huge misconception about the entire GNU project. Thanks for setting me straight  I'll delete my answer in a little bit.

Comment: :/ It won't let me delete the accepted answer

Answer (score -1):

The `linux` tag should stay for questions which are about Linux, but there should be also `gnu` tag for questions about GNU. Not sure about the necessity of adding GNU/Linux tag, as one can already use 2 tags together: `gnu` and `linux`. So a question which addresses both topics can simply use both tags. And a question which is about GNU software (but where the exact kind of kernel is irrelevant) can use just `gnu` tag.

And… I see that `gnu` tag is already present:
https://stackoverflow.com/tags/gnu/info
but it's possible that people don't use it where they should. So they need to learn about it.

I think the correct thing to do here is to make it more obvious what tag(s) to use for question writers. For example, emphasizing in the Linux tag wiki that Linux is only the kernel, and automatically suggesting GNU tag when Linux tag is being added.

There's also an extra tag for Linux: [linux-kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux-kernel).
I created a separate meta "question" for merging it into [linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux), as Linux **is** the kernel.